# Inheritance with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, prototypal-inheritance

I have an account class in javascript. That is my parent class. depositaccout and savingsacount are the children. all this classes are in external javascript files. the calsses are:

```
function account(accountNum, type)
{
    this.accountNum = accountNum;
    this.type = type;
}

function depositAccount(accountNum,type, balance, credit)
{


    this.balance = balance;
    this.credit = credit;   
    account.call(this, accountNum,type);
};


function savingAccount(accountNum,type, amount, yearlyPrime)
{

    this.amount = amount;
    this.yearlyPrime = yearlyPrime;
    account.call(this, accountNum, type);
};
```

In my html page I have another script and I'm trying to initialize a deposit account, meaning I want to create an instance of the account chile- a deposit account. I'm getting an an uncought error for the call method in deposit account class.

Can I get help with that?  What am I doing wrong?
The html script:

```
<script> 
var account = new account(232, "young");
var deposit = new depositaccount(232, "young", 1000, 2555);
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if you've made a typo here, but shouldn't the second `new account()` be `new depositAccount()`? With the code you've provided you're passing in too many arguments otherwise.

Comment: It was a typo. Still no go here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var account = new account(232, "young");
```

You are replacing the `account` function with the object of `account` function.

**Suggestion:**

Its a convention which JavaScript programmers follow, using initial caps for the function names.

Comment: I can't beleive it was that simple! Thank you !

Comment: I will, in 3 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the Mixin pattern here, it's a really useful design pattern for problems like yours.

EDIT: Forget mixin, it would work but a different way, here's a closer match to your problem with sub classing.

e.g.

```
var Account = function(accountNum, type) {
    this.accountNum = accountNum;
    this.type = type;
}

var DepositAccount = function(accountNum, balance, credit) {
    Account.call(this, accountNum, 'deposit');
    this.balance = balance;
    this.credit = credit;   
};

DepositAccount.prototype = Object.create(Account.prototype);
var myAccount = new DepositAccount('12345', '100.00', '10');
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting